# WPF weakly subscribe to the IsEnabledChanged event

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, weak-events, weakeventmanager

Is it possible to *weakly* subscribe to the `UIElement.IsEnabledChanged` event?
Neither the `WeakEventManager<TEventSource, TEventArgs>`

```
WeakEventManager<UIElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>
          .AddHandler(uie, nameof(UIElement.IsEnabledChanged), Element_isEnabledChanged);
```

seems to work because `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` do no extend `TEventArgs`. 
 Nor the `PropertyChangedEventManager`

```
PropertyChangedEventManager
                  .AddHandler(uie, Element_isEnabledChanged, nameof(UIElement.IsEnabled));
```

does work because `UIElement` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`! How are people supposed to safely subscribe to that event?

Comment: I am afraid you have to implement your own. But it's very very simle. See: [Creating a Custom Weak Event Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns#creating-a-custom-weak-event-manager-class).

Comment: The  point is that you usually subscribe to  `DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler` events internally, from inside your own class.  The other scenario is to use `DataTrigger` to handle the changes of other `UIElement` instances' state changes. You would for example trigger on `UIElement.IsEnabled` property changes. UI logic in WPF is designed to be implemented in XAML except the few code-behind scenarios in which you don't need the weak event handling since subscriber and event source share the same lifecycle.

Comment: @BionicCode sadly even custom `WeakEventManager` requires for the event to have `EventArgs`-derived args (due to the `ListenerList`).  Sadly, XAML is very limited in what can you do - in my case I need custom DataGrid row-commiting logic and having it modular as attached behaviour is preferable due to possible behaviour permutation explosion. Though the shared lifecycle is a good point I am baffled something so simple as subscribing from outside would not be possible in GUI framework.

Comment: `DataGrid.OnBeginningEdit`, `DataGrid.OnCellEditEnding`, `DataGrid.OnPreparingCellForEdit` or `DataGrid.OnRowEditEnding` are all `virtual` methods (to name a few) that can be overridden. This doesn't help? You just need to extend `DataGrid`. this way you can customize the existing behavior. This is the intend.

Comment: It is not required to subscribe from 'outside'  the event source in the UI scope. This is part of the design that the WPF framework is enforcing. This is IoC at its finest.

Comment: @BionicCode I can see your point. The original problem is those methods are not correctly called when `IsEnabled` changes, causing the app to crash when on NewItemPlaceholder, thus the attempt to detect changes and manually commit any changes. Perhaps, I should derive the `DataGrid` and fix it, but deriving WPF controls is asking headaches in its own way.

Comment: Whose `IsEnabled` are you interested in? Why do you need this event?

Comment: @BionicCode there is, lets call it a bug, in DataGrid ['newitemplaceholderposition' is not allowed during a transaction begun by 'addnew'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679020/wpf-datagrid-newitemplaceholderposition-is-not-allowed-during-a-transaction-be). While the answers focus how to deal with the immediate effect, they do no answer *at which point* to deal with it. According to my testing, catching whenever `IsEnabled` turns to `false` (for whatever reason) is a good and reliable spot when to deal with this 'bug' and manually commit. Thus I am interested in watching `IsEnabled`.

Comment: How can I reproduce it? When changing tab while editing the current edit gets committed. How can I get this error? Are you sure it is a bug and if so that it still exists?

Comment: @BionicCode the simplest way to reproduce it is hook `PreviewKeyDown` on `DataGrid` and if the key is say, F3, set sender's `IsEnabled` to `false`. It would work when editing existing rows, but if you try to press F3 when editing the 'new row', the app crashes with same message as in the question. Because of the similarities (placeholder removed while editing) I am pretty sure it is the same problem. I have not verified if this is the same with `TabControl`, but in my case it is definitely caused by `IsEnabled`(side effect of one keybindings/commands) while new item placeholder is in focus.